# Activated Office 2016, using wrong email

Tags: microsoft-office-2016

i went to a client's place to set up a pc and install Office 2016.

So when they asked for microsoft email, i used my personal email instead of the user's.

So how do i fix this?

Comment: Uninstall and re-install... if that does not work then probably re-install system....

Comment: The office is now not yet installed but the access to install it is via my microsoft account which is wrong as it should be user's. Anyway i can move this to the user's email ?

Comment: you can open any of the office apps, lets say open word, the file > Office account. Then choose "sign out" and sign in with the clients email and it will now use their email to validate the license.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your licence, you can desactivate the licence on a particular host from your O365 administration panel.

Take a look here : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/deactivate-an-office-365-install-767e3560-96ed-4b1c-806d-2fe01c529b1b#ID0EABAAA=signinmsa